# Why can't I set a class array property in __construct()?

Tags: php

When running this example, I get "Undefined variable: cfg in{...}"
If I take out the $this->cfg and replace it with just $cfg, this part works. Is there something special that must be done when setting a php class property that is an array?
Does every element in an array need set individually, or can it be set in a similar way to this?

```
class DBHandler
{
    private $cfg;
    private String $dbName;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cfg = parse_ini_file("../config.ini");
        $this->dbName = $cfg["database"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `$this->cfg` to access the variable you put in `$this->cfg`

Comment: `$this->dbName = $cfg["database"];` should be `$this->dbName = $this->cfg['database'];`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @apokryfos
He answered this question in his comment above. You can set a class array property in the constructor in php, but I was subsequently trying to get an element out of the class's array without using $this->cfg on the next line, which was messing it up.